# Counting, Probability and Binomial Coefficients

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients

If $$P_{2n+2}=\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2}{2n+2 \choose k}p^kq^{2n+2-k}$$

and,

$$P_{2n}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n \choose k}p^kq^{2n-k}$$

where $0<p<q<1$ and $q=1-p$

Prove that

$$P_{2n+2}=P_{2n}+{2n \choose n}p^{n+2}q^n-{2n \choose {n+1}}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}$$

$\mathbf {Inspiration:}$ A and B play a series of games where the probability of winning $\mathit p$ for A is kept less than 0.5. However A gets to choose in advance the total no. of plays. To win the game one must score more than half the games . If the total no. of games is to be even, How many plays should A choose?

$\mathbf {Here}$ $P_{2n}$ and $P_{2n+2}$ represents the probability of A winning the play in $2n$ and $2n+2$ games where $2n$ is considered the optimum number of games

Comment: This is perhaps true. It reduces to $\binom{2 n}{n+1} \left((p-1)^2-\, _2F_1\left(1,1-n;n+2;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)\right)+(p-1) p \binom{2 n}{n}=(p-1) p \binom{2 (n+1)}{n+2} \, _2F_1\left(1,-n;n+3;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)$. Though I do not know how to prove this.

Answer (score 3):

We consider $(p+q)^2P_{2n}$ instead of $P_{2n}$ (because then our identity will be homogeneous). Then, we will simply compare coefficents of monomials $p^kq^{2n+2-k}$ in both sides of identity.

Note that (from equality $p+q=1$)
$$
P_{2n}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n \choose k}p^kq^{2n-k}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n \choose k}p^kq^{2n-k} (p+q)^2,
$$
which equals
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n \choose k}p^kq^{2n-k} (p^2+2pq+q^2)=
\\
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n \choose k}p^{k+2}q^{2n-k}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}2{2n \choose k}p^{k+1}q^{2n-k+1}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n \choose k}p^{k}q^{2n-k+2}=
\\
\sum_{k=n+3}^{2n+2}{2n \choose k-2}p^{k}q^{2n+2-k}+\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+1}2{2n \choose k-1}p^{k}q^{2n+2-k}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{2n \choose k}p^{k}q^{2n-k+2}.
$$

Therefore, $P_{2n}$ equals
$$
\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2}\left({2n \choose k}+2{2n \choose k-1}+{2n \choose k-2}\right)p^kq^{2n+2-k}-\left({2n \choose n}p^{n+2}q^{n}-{2n \choose n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}\right).
$$

We also know that 
$$
{2n \choose k}+2{2n \choose k-1}+{2n \choose k-2}=\left({2n \choose k}+{2n \choose k-1}\right)+\left({2n \choose k-1}+{2n \choose k-2}\right)=
\\
{2n+1 \choose k}+{2n+1 \choose k-1}={2n+2 \choose k},
$$
so we obtain
$$
P_{2n}=\sum_{k=n+2}^{2n+2}{2n+2 \choose k}p^kq^{2n+2-k}=P_{2n+2}-\left({2n \choose n}p^{n+2}q^{n}-{2n \choose n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}\right).
$$
Hence,
$$
P_{2n+2}=P_{2n}+{2n \choose n}p^{n+2}q^{n}-{2n \choose n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1},
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The equality reduces to
$$
\binom{2 n}{n+1} p^{n+1} (1-p)^{n-1} \, _2F_1\left(1,1-n;n+2;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)+\binom{2 n}{n} p^{n+2} (1-p)^n-\binom{2 n}{n+1} p^{n+1} (1-p)^{n+1}=\binom{2 (n+1)}{n+2} (1-p)^{-n+2 (n+1)-2} p^{n+2} \, _2F_1\left(1,-n;n+3;\frac{p}{p-1}\right)
$$
Let $w=p/(1-p)$, then the above is
$$
\binom{2 n}{n+1} \left((w+1)^2 \, _2F_1(1,1-n;n+2;-w)-1\right)+w \binom{2 n}{n}=w \binom{2 (n+1)}{n+2} \, _2F_1(1,-n;n+3;-w)
$$
We can then extract the coefficient for $w^m$ from both side for $m \in \{0,\dots,n\}$ to see that this equality holds.

Answer (score 1):

Forget the requirement that $0<p<q<1$; it is unnecessary. So let $p$ and $q$
be any reals satisfying $p+q=1$.

Also, let me extend the stage a little bit:

> **Definition.** Let $m$ and $n$ be integers such that $n\geq m\geq0$. Then, we
>   let
>   \begin{equation}
> Q_{n,m}=\sum_{k=m}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}.
> \end{equation}

With this definition, your $P_{2n}$ is $Q_{2n,n+1}$, while your $P_{2n+2}$ is
$Q_{2n+2,n+2}$. Thus, your claim becomes:

> **Theorem 1.** Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> Q_{2n+2,n+2}=Q_{2n,n+1}+\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n+2}q^{n}-\dbinom{2n}{n+1}
> p^{n+1}q^{n+1}.
> \end{equation}

I shall derive this from the following:

> **Lemma 2.** Let $m$ and $n$ be integers such that $n\geq m\geq1$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> Q_{n,m}=Q_{n-1,m-1}-\dbinom{n-1}{m-1}p^{m-1}q^{n-m+1}.
> \end{equation}

*Proof of Lemma 2.* From $n\geq m\geq1$, we obtain $n-1\geq m-1\geq0$. Now,
the definition of $Q_{n-1,m-1}$ yields
\begin{equation}
Q_{n-1,m-1}=\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}\underbrace{q^{n-1-k}
}_{=q^{n-k-1}}=\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k-1}.
\label{darij1.pf.l2.0}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

But the definition of $Q_{n,m}$ yields
\begin{align}
Q_{n,m}  &  =\sum_{k=m}^{n}\underbrace{\dbinom{n}{k}}_{\substack{=\dbinom
{n-1}{k-1}+\dbinom{n-1}{k}\\\text{(by the recurrence of the binomial
coefficients)}}}p^{k}q^{n-k}=\sum_{k=m}^{n}\left(  \dbinom{n-1}{k-1}
+\dbinom{n-1}{k}\right)  p^{k}q^{n-k}\nonumber\\
&  =\sum_{k=m}^{n}\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k}q^{n-k}+\sum_{k=m}^{n}\dbinom{n-1}
{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}\nonumber\\
&  =\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\underbrace{\dbinom{n-1}{\left(  k+1\right)  -1}
}_{=\dbinom{n-1}{k}}p^{k+1}\underbrace{q^{n-\left(  k+1\right)  }}
_{=q^{n-k-1}}+\sum_{k=m}^{n}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}\nonumber\\
&  \qquad\left(  \text{here, we have substituted }k+1\text{ for }k\text{ in
the first sum}\right) \nonumber\\
&  =\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k+1}q^{n-k-1}+\sum_{k=m}^{n}
\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}.
\label{darij1.pf.l2.1}
\tag{2}
\end{align}

But we have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=m-1}^{n}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}=\sum_{k=m}^{n}\dbinom{n-1}{k}
p^{k}q^{n-k}+\dbinom{n-1}{m-1}p^{m-1}q^{n-\left(  m-1\right)  }
\end{equation}
and
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=m-1}^{n}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k} &  =\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom
{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}+\underbrace{\dbinom{n-1}{n}}_{\substack{=0\\\text{(since
}n-1\geq0\text{ and }n-1<n\text{)}}}p^{n}q^{n-n}\\
&  =\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}.
\end{align*}
Comparing these two equalities, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=m}^{n}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}+\dbinom{n-1}{m-1}p^{m-1}q^{n-\left(
m-1\right)  }=\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}.
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=m}^{n}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}=\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}
{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}-\dbinom{n-1}{m-1}p^{m-1}q^{n-\left(  m-1\right)  }.
\end{equation}
Hence, \eqref{darij1.pf.l2.1} becomes
\begin{align*}
Q_{n,m} &  =\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k+1}q^{n-k-1}+\underbrace{\sum
_{k=m}^{n}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}}_{=\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}
{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}-\dbinom{n-1}{m-1}p^{m-1}q^{n-\left(  m-1\right)  }}\\
&  =\underbrace{\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k+1}q^{n-k-1}+\sum
_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}}_{=\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}
{k}\left(  p^{k+1}q^{n-k-1}+p^{k}q^{n-k}\right)  }-\dbinom{n-1}{m-1}
p^{m-1}\underbrace{q^{n-\left(  m-1\right)  }}_{=q^{n-m+1}}\\
&  =\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}\left(  \underbrace{p^{k+1}}_{=pp^{k}
}q^{n-k-1}+p^{k}\underbrace{q^{n-k}}_{=qq^{n-k-1}}\right)  -\dbinom{n-1}
{m-1}p^{m-1}q^{n-m+1}\\
&  =\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}\underbrace{\left(  pp^{k}q^{n-k-1}
+p^{k}qq^{n-k-1}\right)  }_{\substack{=\left(  p+q\right)  p^{k}
q^{n-k-1}=p^{k}q^{n-k-1}\\\text{(since }p+q=1\text{)}}}-\dbinom{n-1}
{m-1}p^{m-1}q^{n-m+1}\\
&  =\underbrace{\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}\dbinom{n-1}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k-1}}
_{\substack{=Q_{n-1,m-1}\\\text{(by \eqref{darij1.pf.l2.0})}}}-\dbinom
{n-1}{m-1}p^{m-1}q^{n-m+1}\\
&  =Q_{n-1,m-1}-\dbinom{n-1}{m-1}p^{m-1}q^{n-m+1}.
\end{align*}
This proves Lemma 2. $\blacksquare$

*Proof of Theorem 1.* We have $\left(  1-q-pq\right)  -p^{2}=-\left(
p+1\right)  \underbrace{\left(  p+q-1\right)  }_{\substack{=0\\\text{(since
}p+q=1\text{)}}}=0$, thus $1-q-pq=p^{2}$.

Lemma 2 (applied to $2n+2$ and $n+2$ instead of $n$ and $m$) yields
\begin{align}
Q_{2n+2,n+2}  & =\underbrace{Q_{2n+1,n+1}}_{\substack{=Q_{2n,n}-\dbinom{2n}
{n}p^{n}q^{\left(  2n+1\right)  -\left(  n+1\right)  +1}\\\text{(by Lemma 2,
applied to }2n+1\text{ and }n+1\\\text{instead of }n\text{ and }m\text{)}
}}-\underbrace{\dbinom{2n+1}{n+1}}_{\substack{=\dbinom{2n}{n}+\dbinom{2n}
{n+1}\\\text{(by the recurrence of the binomial coefficients)}}}p^{n+1}
\underbrace{q^{\left(  2n+2\right)  -\left(  n+2\right)  +1}}_{=q^{n+1}
}\nonumber\\
& =Q_{2n,n}-\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n}\underbrace{q^{\left(  2n+1\right)  -\left(
n+1\right)  +1}}_{=q^{n+1}}-\underbrace{\left(  \dbinom{2n}{n}+\dbinom
{2n}{n+1}\right)  p^{n+1}q^{n+1}}_{=\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}+\dbinom
{2n}{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}}\nonumber\\
& =Q_{2n,n}-\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n}q^{n+1}-\left(  \dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n+1}
q^{n+1}+\dbinom{2n}{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}\right)  \nonumber\\
& =Q_{2n,n}-\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n}q^{n+1}-\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}
-\dbinom{2n}{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}.
\label{darij1.pf.t1.1}
\tag{3}
\end{align}
But the definition of $Q_{2n,n+1}$ yields $Q_{2n,n+1}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}
\dbinom{2n}{k}p^{k}q^{2n-k}$. Meanwhile, the definition of $Q_{2n,n}$ yields
\begin{align*}
Q_{2n,n}  & =\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\dbinom{2n}{k}p^{k}q^{2n-k}=\underbrace{\sum
_{k=n+1}^{2n}\dbinom{2n}{k}p^{k}q^{2n-k}}_{=Q_{2n,n+1}}+\dbinom{2n}{n}
p^{n}\underbrace{q^{2n-n}}_{=q^{n}}\\
& =Q_{2n,n+1}+\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n}q^{n}.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\eqref{darij1.pf.t1.1} becomes
\begin{align*}
Q_{2n+2,n+2}  & =\underbrace{Q_{2n,n}}_{=Q_{2n,n+1}+\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n}q^{n}
}-\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n}q^{n+1}-\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}-\dbinom{2n}
{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}\\
& =Q_{2n,n+1}+\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n}q^{n}-\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n}q^{n+1}-\dbinom
{2n}{n}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}-\dbinom{2n}{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}\\
& =Q_{2n,n+1}+\dbinom{2n}{n}\underbrace{\left(  p^{n}q^{n}-p^{n}
q^{n+1}-p^{n+1}q^{n+1}\right)  }_{=\left(  1-q-pq\right)  p^{n}q^{n}}
-\dbinom{2n}{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}\\
& =Q_{2n,n+1}+\dbinom{2n}{n}\underbrace{\left(  1-q-pq\right)  }_{=p^{2}}
p^{n}q^{n}-\dbinom{2n}{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}\\
& =Q_{2n,n+1}+\dbinom{2n}{n}\underbrace{p^{2}p^{n}}_{=p^{n+2}}q^{n}
-\dbinom{2n}{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}\\
& =Q_{2n,n+1}+\dbinom{2n}{n}p^{n+2}q^{n}-\dbinom{2n}{n+1}p^{n+1}q^{n+1}.
\end{align*}
This proves Theorem 1. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

We have for the first sum

$$S = \sum_{k=0}^n {2n+2\choose k+n+2} p^{k+n+2} q^{n-k}$$

and for the second one

$$T = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {2n\choose k+n+1} p^{k+n+1} q^{n-1-k}$$

and seek to show

$$S-T =
{2n\choose n} p^{n+2} q^n - {2n\choose n+1} p^{n+1} q^{n+1}$$

where $p+q=1.$ We see that with

$$Q_n = \sum_{k=0}^n {2n+2\choose k+n+2} p^{k+n+2} q^{n-k}$$

the claim becomes

$$Q_n - Q_{n-1} =
{2n\choose n} p^{n+2} q^n - {2n\choose n+1} p^{n+1} q^{n+1}.$$

Now

$$Q_n = p^{n+2} q^n
\sum_{k=0}^n {2n+2\choose k+n+2} p^{k} q^{-k}
= p^{n+2} q^n
\sum_{k=0}^n {2n+2\choose n-k} p^{k} q^{-k}
\\ = p^{n+2} q^n
\sum_{k=0}^n  p^{k} q^{-k}
[z^{n-k}] (1+z)^{2n+2}
= p^{n+2} q^n  [z^n] (1+z)^{2n+2}
\sum_{k=0}^n  p^{k} q^{-k} z^k.$$

We may extend $k$ beyond $n$ owing to the coefficient extrator $[z^n]$
in front:

$$p^{n+2} q^n  [z^n] (1+z)^{2n+2}
\sum_{k\ge 0}  p^{k} q^{-k} z^k
= p^{n+2} q^n  [z^n] (1+z)^{2n+2} \frac{1}{1-pz/q}
\\ = p^2  [z^n] (1+pqz)^{2n+2} \frac{1}{1-p^2z}.$$

We thus have

$$Q_{n-1} = p^2  [z^{n-1}] (1+pqz)^{2n} \frac{1}{1-p^2z}
\\ = p^2  [z^n] z (1+pqz)^{2n} \frac{1}{1-p^2z}.$$

Subtracting we find

$$Q_n - Q_{n-1}
= p^2  [z^n] ((1+pqz)^2-z) (1+pqz)^{2n} \frac{1}{1-p^2z}
\\ = p^2  [z^n] (1-p^2 z) (1-q^2 z)
(1+pqz)^{2n} \frac{1}{1-p^2z}
\\ = p^2  [z^n] (1-q^2 z) (1+pqz)^{2n}
\\ = p^2  [z^n]  (1+pqz)^{2n}
- p^2  [z^n] q^2 z (1+pqz)^{2n}
\\ = p^2 p^n q^n {2n\choose n}
- p^2 q^2 [z^{n-1}] (1+pqz)^{2n}
\\ = p^{n+2} q^n {2n\choose n}
- p^2  q^2 p^{n-1} q^{n-1} {2n\choose n-1}.$$

This is indeed

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
p^{n+2} q^n {2n\choose n}
- p^{n+1} q^{n+1} {2n\choose n+1}}$$

as claimed.

**Remark.** It  might be simpler not  to merge the $p^n  q^n$ into the
coefficient extractor. Further commentary TBA.